# Merge files created with JSON arrays into a single file

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, file-io

just to get you started, I want to merge json array files into a single file, with (comma) appended to the end of the array.

`MemoryError` now in my code, please help me!

**in my code >**

```
import os, sys
path = "censored"
dirs = os.listdir(path)

save_list = []

s = ""
for file in dirs:
   save_list.append(file)
for i in range(len(save_list)):
    f = open(path + save_list[i], 'r')
    s += f.read()
    s += s.replace("]", "],")

f.close()
ff = open("a", 'w')
ff.write(s)
ff.close()
print("done")
```

**Error >**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    s += s.replace("]", "],")
MemoryError
```

**Want result**

```
file "a" in substance
[{a:b}]
file "b" in substance
[{c:d}]

file "c" want result substance
[{a:b}], [{c:d}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code, you're opening every single file one after another, and only closing the last one. You should be opening and closing each file after you are done with it to make it more memory efficient.

You can actually progressively write to the output file instead of storing it as a string in memory and writing it at one shot.

There's actually no need to save all files from `dir` into `save_list` and reaccess it in another loop. So you can omit `save_list`.

Putting everything together, you'll get the following code snippet:

```
# everything above as follows

for file in dirs:
    curr_file_path = path + file
    curr_file_string = ""

    # using this would close the file automatically
    with open(curr_file_path, 'r') as f:
        raw_file = f.read()
        curr_file_string = raw_file.replace("]", "],")

   # open the output file and set the mode to append ('a') to batch write
   # similarly, this will close the output file after every write
   with open("output file", "a") as out_f:
       out_f.write(curr_file_string)

print("done")
```